# Some questions on pointer to member of class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I want to ask about the behaviour of compiler in the following scenario :-

```
class A 
{
    public:
          int n;
          int *ptrClass;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    int A::*ptr;

    ptr = &A::n;
    a.ptrClass = &a.n;

    cout << "\nPointer points to the memory address: " << ptr;
    cout << "\nPointer points to the value: " << a.*ptr;

    cout << "\nPointer points to the memory address: " << a.ptrClass;
    cout << "\nPointer points to the value: " << *a.ptrClass;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

## Ques 1:-

> Why the ptr is accessible in the main without any reference to the
>   class A, 
>          something like a.ptr as, I have declared ptr as int A:: *ptr; 
>          Doesn't it make the ptr as a class member ?

## Ques 2:-

> When I run the above program, I noticed, that the memory address of n
>   of class
>          A was different when fetched by ptr, and by a.ptrClass. Didn't get that. Any 
>          explainations please.

The questions might be very basic, but please help.

Comment: Try `cout << boolalpha;` You will notice that `cout << ptr` actually converts `ptr` to a bool (`ptr != nullptr`) and prints that bool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the ptr is accessible in the main without any reference to the class A, something like a.ptr as, I have declared ptr as int A:: *ptr; Doesn't it make the ptr as a class member ?

```
int A::* ptr;
```

Does not declare `ptr` as a member of class `A`. It rather declares `ptr` as a pointer to a data member of class `A` that is of type `int`. For example:

```
class A {
public:
    int i0;
    int i1;
};

int main() {
    int A::* mptr;
    mptr = &A::i0;
    mptr = &A::i1;
}
```

Pointer-to-members do not point to a specific memory address, they're much like offsets. For example:

```
int main() {
    A a[2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

    int A::* mptr = &A::i0;
    // print the first data member (i0) of a[0] and a[1]
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i].*mptr << "\n";
    }

    mptr = &A::i1;
    // print the second data member (i1) of a[0] and a[1]
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i].*mptr << "\n";
    }
}
```

A possible memory layout of objects of class `A`:

```
class A {
public:
    int i0;
    int i1;
};

A a = {42, 21};
```

```
+-a--------------+
| +-i0-+  +-i1-+ |
| | 42 |  | 21 | |
| +----+  +----+ |
+----------------+
```

Now, we add the pointers:

```
int* pi1 = &a.i1;
int A::* mpi1 = &A::i1;
A* pa = &a;
```

```
+-a--------------+
| +-i0-+  +-i1-+ |
| | 42 |  | 21 | |
| +----+  +----+ |
+---------^------+
^         | pi1
| pa
```

Both `pi1` and `pa` point to specific objects. On the other hand, `mpi1` is an offset into *an* (= any) object of type `A`:

```
+-A--------------+
| +-i0-+  +-i1-+ |
| |    |  |    | |
| +----+  +----+ |
~~~~~~~~~~^ mpi1 |
+----------------+
```

We can now combine `mpi1` to `pa` to get to the specific object `a.i1`:

```
+-a--------------+
| +-i0-+  +-i1-+ |
| | 42 |  | 21 | |
| +----+  +----+ |
+---------^------+
^~~~~~~~~~+ mpi1
| pa
```

This is written as:

```
pa->*mpi1 // this expression refers to `a.i1` aka `*pi1`
```

so we can identify:

```
&(pa->*mpi1) == pi1
```

If we interpret the addresses and the offset as integer values, we might get something like:

```
pa   == 0x7fff39519328
pi1  == 0x7fff3951932c
mpi1 == 4
```

Therefore, we can see that `8 + 4 == 12 == 0xc`, that is, "pa + mpi1 == pi1". Do not take this too literally, it isn't allowed in C++ to perform this addition: `pa + mpi1` is not legal C++. Additionally, it isn't guaranteed for all platforms that we can just add those two values. But it explains a popular implementation on x86.

---

> When I run the above program, I noticed, that the memory address of n of class A was different when fetched by ptr, and by a.ptrClass. Didn't get that. Any explainations please.

```
cout << "\nPointer points to the memory address: " << ptr;
```

This line actually does

```
cout << "\nPointer points to the memory address: " << (bool)ptr;
```

Which is the same as

```
cout << "\nPointer points to the memory address: " << (ptr != nullptr);
```

To see this, try

```
cout << boolalpha;
```

which prints boolean values as strings *true* / *false*.

On the other hand, this line:

```
cout << "\nPointer points to the memory address: " << a.ptrClass;
```

does a conversion to `void*`. This is *the* raw memory pointer type in C++. Every pointer to a specific object can be converted to a `void*`, pointing to the same memory location. The `cout << some_void_star` operation prints the address of raw memory this `void*` points to. For many hardware architectures, the address is, or can be represented as, an integer. This integer representation is typically printed for the operation `cout << some_void_star`.

Pointer-to-members are not pointers to specific objects and are therefore not allowed to be converted to `void*` (they do not point to a specific address). Printing their value interpreted as an integer is quite tricky. You can try:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
// this code will probably produce wrong results on big endian architectures
static_assert(sizeof(unsigned long long) >= sizeof(mpi1));
unsigned long long as_integer;
std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&mpi1), sizeof(mpi1),
            reinterpret_cast<char*>(&as_integer));
std::cout << as_integer;
```

Comment: thanks a ton dyp for this tremendous response. Can you elaborate about the line 'Pointer-to-members do not point to a specific memory address, they're much like offsets.'. What are offsets here ? And also ptrClass conversion to void pointer ?

Comment: @King I've tried to address your new questions. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks a lot ...!! that really helps and clarifies my doubts..!! thank you again..!!